# Why does my outdoor tap have a diameter of 1-1/4" inches, not the standard 1"?

Tags: plumbing, outdoor, taps

The outdoor tap for the front yard of our house has an outer diameter of 1-1/4" inches, so it is useless for attaching a garden hose.  A standard tap is more like 1" in diameter.

My question is: Why?  And is there anything I can do about it, short of installing a new tap?  Anybody seen this before?

It looks like an adapter (a ring with a normal hose thread inside and larger thread outside) may have been screwed on to create the wider outer diameter.  But if that's the case I've been unsuccessful in removing it with the tools I have. A plumber that looked at it speculated that it had been modified for something like a backflow preventer.

I've added a picture below.

[image]

Comment: Pictures or it didn't happen (grin). Need to see what's being described.

Comment: If there **is** an adapter (ring threaded normal hose thread and larger thread inside and outside) you can probably cut most of the way through it (not into the original threads, so use restraint) and then try a cold chisel to move it/split it off the hose bibb. Or pay a plumber to use a bigger wrench.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, your cutter suggestion is a good one, thx.  I'll try WD-40 before that.

Comment: @Fiasco, I've added a picture.

Comment: Try heating it and turning off the adapter. It also looks like it may have been soldered on there. Make sure it is not soldered on there. If it is heat it and remove as much of the solder with some steel wool. Then get hot and turn it off with a small monkey wrench.

Comment: Remains of an ancient Vacuum Breaker? Threads are quite short and there appears to be a step or o-ring groove that a seal gasket would fit in. @Ecnerwal suggestion to cut just short of threads is a fairly standard removal method, a little heat with care to not damage internal seals will help.